# CSS - float:left not pushing div away/working properly

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-float

I have two div's next to each other but I cannot seem to get float: left to work properly and achieve what I want. Every time, the left div will still cut into/overlap onto the right div like so (This the dynamic version of my code with some jQuery code which changes the size of the divs based on user input): https://gyazo.com/b373205412f4ba18f32dad0f3cf877d2

Here is the static version of my code where I change the width/height manually. As you can see I have float: left on div5brother, but div5 still overlaps onto it. jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/92etqaxk/10/

This is what I am trying to recreate:
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 60px;
  width: 205px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div3 > span {
  transform: translate(-10%, -55%) rotate(-45deg);
  font-size: 11px;
}

.div4 {
  border-top: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.div5container {
  width: 205px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.div5 {
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 235px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.div5brother {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -80px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  float: left;

}

.div5brother > span {
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3"><span>Pipe O.D.</span>

      <div class="div5container">
        <div class="elem div5">
        </div>
        <div class="elem div5brother">
          <span>Min. Cutter Travel</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="elem div4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the overlapping is due to you making the div5 element 30px wider than its container. I changed its width from `width: 235px;` to `width: 205px;` and the overlapping is gone and it seems to match the image. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d403e71g/1/) with my changes.

Comment: I want to be able to adjust the width to 250px and have the 2 sided border be pushed to the left. The width of div5 should not matter